# realloc: invalid old size

Tags: c++, malloc, runtime-error

I have found many threads on this error, but have been unable to find a solution that works for me. I am trying to read data from a PGM image and put it into a matrix. My problem is that the reallocation of memory fails with the error `realloc: invalid old size`. Below is a excerpt from the code that shows how the reallocation is done.

```
typedef struct num_matrix {
   int ** data;
   int rows;
   int cols;
} matrix;

[in loadPGMImageFromFilename]
matrix m;
m.data = (int**)malloc(0*sizeof(int));
loadPGMImageData(m);

[in void loadPGMImageData(matrix &m)]
ss >> m.rows >> m.cols; // <- sets rows and cols, seems to work
allocateMatrixMemory(m);

void allocateMatrixMemory(matrix &m) {
   int** temp = (int**) realloc(m.data, m.rows*sizeof(int)); // <- ERROR
   //more stuff
}
```

Comment: `(int**)malloc(0*sizeof(int));`? Is this intentional?

Comment: is it [tag:c]??...

Comment: `ss >> m.rows >> m.cols;` and what should that be or do?

Comment: Don't do the initial 0-byte allocation, just set `m.data` to `NULL` and pass that to `realloc()` when you need to grow the matrix. Passing `NULL` to `realloc()` is well-defined and perfectly safe, it makes it work like `malloc()`. Also drop the casts, this isn't C++ ... or is it? Those stream reads look suspicious.

Comment: oh, I guess it's a mix of c and c++.
ss >> m.rows >> m.cols, I only showed the code I considered important. What happens is I read the contents of the file into a stringstream and that row inserts the values into the variables.

Comment: @unwind I tried changing the malloc of m.data to m.data = NULL instead. I that what you meant? With that change I got `realloc: invalid pointer` instead.

Comment: @FabianJonsson There's no such thing as "a mix between C and C++", if it's C++ it's C++. :) And yes, that's what I meant, set the `data` pointer to `nullptr` (it's C++, remember) before the size is known. Better yet, throw this out and use e.g. `std::vector` instead, you're in C++ after all.

Comment: If you are using `int **` then you need to set up an array of pointers, however you actually try to malloc a contiguous block.

Comment: @LPs c doesn't have the >> operator; which would make this c++

Comment: @UKMonkey ..that is the reason I wrote that comment...

Comment: @unwind "Better yet, throw this out and use e.g. std::vector instead, you're in C++ after all.". Heh, that's probably the way to go atm. I was somehow stuck in thinking that I needed to use malloc/realloc because I was building on a sample code that was written in C. But since I've already used C++, I guess there's no point in not making use of all the C++ features... :)

Answer (score -4):

Out of top of my head, 
after this line -> m.data = (int**)malloc(0*sizeof(int)); m.data is null.
You cannot realloc null.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: and this may be a valid pointer: `If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free(). `

Comment: A `realloc` with a `NULL` pointer as first parameter is the same as a `malloc` call.